# How to add label in bootstrap multiselect?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

whether we have any option here to show the image as default.

**Code:**

```
<select id="example-post" style="width:120px;!important;" class="footerSelect" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">test</option>
    <option value="2">test1</option>
    <option value="3">test2 </option>             

</select>

 $('.multiselect-selected-text').text('Options');
```

[image]

Here  instead of options i want to show the Image as default.

Sample Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would just add the glyphicon within the button.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
```

Full example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d7t01u4/2/)**

Furthermore you can use jQuery to dynamically add such elements.

```
var span = $('<span></span>');
span.addClass('glyphicon');
span.addClass('glyphicon-pencil');
$('#foo').html(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer Found:

I just added this.

`$('.multiselect-selected-text').addClass('fa fa-check-square-o fa-6');`

Thanks